# Bio "blood magic" how would it work in science fantasy

Tags: magic, blood

[image]I'm putting together a story that centers around "blood magic" and ancient civilization that uses some "rare crystals" as infinite source of Energy.  the blood magic comes in gas form [from any source of living being but only if it made contact with your blood. 
after getting control of someone's blood u can manipulate its form and use the blood iron as nano blades or sharp gas form. 
now  I'm having issues finding a reasonable way to implement this xD

if it possible how would u Explain it in ancient science way and modern science. 
Ty for help and sry for bad English :P

Comment: I think you invited so much magic that you don't need anything more than "handwavium" explanation.

Comment: maybe, the idea that its the only unnatural thing in my universe  and most of the population cant use it.

Comment: what you mean implement it ? as combat or martial arts?  or some civilian use ? if you mean as combat or martial arts, i think avatar the last airbender do a good job with the water bending technique for you to copy, sure it not show the lethality or more lethal application but its nice enough as a  basis.

Comment: What i mean by implement is it  if u got one of those "blood magic" guys in a lab  and started to study his body                                                                                          [with modern science] what is the best way to do it? [explaining his unnatural power [i can just make god and magic stuff but the catch here to make it more realistic]                       lets just say they are from different planets  so u can play a bit with this

Comment: @The Bigs so what you want is a semi-plausible explanation of this ability that would tap into science?

Comment: maybe... :I  Is it impossible to do that?

Comment: If you would like a science based answer then you need the [tag:science-based] tag. You would also need to make it a bit clearer what you're asking - you want to put them into the blood of others then control them to break down their blood into blades? Or something to do with a "sharp gas", could you clarify? (remembering the one question per post rule from the [help]).

Answer (score 2):

Research report:
The overly limited time span granted and the subject's uncooperative nature made it so not few tests could be conducted; further experiments will be necessary to determine the full capabilities of the "ability" in question.

The subject's ability seems directly connected with its own and other's blood and focused on utilizing it predominantly as a means of offense. While initially it'd seem like the blood is somehow in the state of "gas", which would be impossible given blood is a  [colloid](http://www.scienceclarified.com/Ci-Co/Colloid.html), the blood manipulated by the subject is in fact kept in a mist-like state. It's yet unknown how the subject is capable of keeping it afloat, but after x-Ray analysis, the subject has shown to posses alterations in its brain, with a more developed pineal gland, leading me to theorize the subject might be capable of limited telekinesis, which would be directly bound to its own genetic code, as the ability was only shown to take effect after a victim had contact with the subject's blood. As for now, it is assumed that the subject's [macrophages](https://www.immunology.org/public-information/bitesized-immunology/cells/macrophages), will actively travel towards and "mark" a victim's blood so that it's telekinetic abilities can recognize and control it, given their hyperactivity when compared to normal human cells.

In addition, the subject has demonstrated affinity with the iron present in the blood, being able to extract and reshape it at will. How the subject is capable of doing this without any visible apparatuses is beyond current science under my own knowledge. It is again speculated the subject has some sort of affinity with this metal in particular or [ferrokinetic](https://powerlisting.fandom.com/wiki/Metal_Manipulation) ability.

Hopefully new tests will reveal further information about the subject's biology and ability. We're yet to confirm whether the subject can pressurize the blood to [use it as a cutting weapon](https://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/energy/question553.htm). A new report will be sent as soon as we manage to gather relevant Data. Doctor [redacted] out.

Comment: WOW thanks man :D really cool idea , still would be nice to see more comments and ideas

Comment: @TheBigs don't worry, I'm pretty sure you'll get great answers if you wait a little, I know I usually do.

Comment: asking for more help xD  more comments and ideas guys?